# Why is my JScrollPane not working?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

Can someone work out why my `JScrollPane` is not working. Perhaps something I may have missed. I realize this might be silly without any more context than what I've shown but please ask and I shall be happy to provide more.

```
public ApplicationFrame(String title, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        // Constructor for the ApplicationFrame, no implicit Construc.
        setTitle(title);
        setResizable(true);
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/topLeft.png")).getImage());
        topMostMenuBar = new TopMenuBar(this);
        setJMenuBar(topMostMenuBar.getMyJMenuBar());
        paneEdge = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray);
        blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        this.frameContent = new ApplicationPanel() {
            //@Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(TI, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        mainImageScrollPane = new JScrollPane(frameContent);
        statusPanel = new ApplicationPanel(new Color(0xfff0f0f0));
        leftPanel = new ApplicationPanel(new Color(0xfff0f0f0));
        testPanel = new ColorPanel(new Color(0xfff0f0f0));
        testPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,300));
        add(mainImageScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        Container visibleArea = getContentPane();
        visibleArea.add(frameContent);
        setVisible(true);
        do {
            loadImageIn();
        } while (!initLoadSuccess);
        initButtons();
        leftPanel.add(testPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    } // end Constructor **
```

This is a big piece of code so I'm not sure how to make an SSCCE out of it. What youre looking at is the constructor to my subclass of a `JFrame`, which holds 3 panels. The `ApplicationPanel` is at this point just a `JPanel`. The `loadImageIn()` method opens a filechooser and then loads the chosen image which is painted onto `frameContent`. The image displays fine, everything works, except when I resize the window, there are no scrollbars.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line, which adds the `ApplicationPanel` to the `visibleArea`...

```
visibleArea.add(frameContent);
```

Maybe you actually mean this, which adds the `JScrollPane` to the `visibleArea` (and the `JScrollPane` already contains the `ApplicationPanel`)...

```
visibleArea.add(mainImageScrollPane);
```

When you call `new JScrollPane(frameContent)`, it doesn't do anything to the panel inside it, it just adds a wrapper around the outside. So, if you want the ability to scroll, you need to refer to the `JScrollPane` wrapper, rather than the panel itself.

Comment: Cheers, that was it. I had to step out as this was giving me a headache. Next time I will definitely work out how to reduce my problem down to an SSCCE. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem :-) glad to help. FYI, I think you did good with your SSCCE code - it was a good length and showed all the content we needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any size for your `frameContent`. Is it intentional?

Additionally your `frameContent` is later on being added to `visibleArea`. Meaning no longer in the `mainImageScrollPane` `JScrollPane`

Maybe you wanna have:
`visibleArea.add(mainImageScrollPane);`, but you need to set your panel size

Answer (score 0):

```
mainImageScrollPane.setViewportView(<component_to_be_scrollable>);
```