# JScrollPane doesn't work for my JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

first of all I must say that I have checked these questions and didn't find my answer :

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009773/jscrollpane-does-not-appear-when-using-it-on-a-jpanel) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031637/adding-jpanel-to-jscrollpane)  ,  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393480/java-jpanel-inside-jscrollpane) , [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009773/jscrollpane-does-not-appear-when-using-it-on-a-jpanel) ,  [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037156/jscrollpane-problem) , [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117233/why-is-my-jscrollpane-not-working) ,  [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037156/jscrollpane-problem)

and many other questions like so

also I have checked these tutorials and examples:

[1](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node63.html)  ,  [9](http://www.coderanch.com/t/547005/GUI/java/Add-JPanel-JScrollPane) , [10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) , [11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

and many other sites. but I couldn't fix my problem.

and 
this is the simple kind of my code:

```
public class Question extends JFrame {
public Question() {
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(d.width, d.height);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, d.height));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        panel.add(new JButton("kjdh"));
    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Question();
} 
}
```

but the `JScrollPane` doesn't appear. I have tested many things. I have changed the way adding `panel` and `scrollPane` to my `frame` but it didn't work. can any one help me plz?

Comment: Have you tried scrollPane.add(panel), and adding only the panel?

Comment: Did you try the framework to calculate dimensions? And right, preferred size requires preferences configuration, use the full size.

Comment: You already added the jpanel inside scrollpane so there is no need to add the jpanel again in frame. Avoid adding unnecessary code like adding jpanel twice. Just remove the line `getContentPane().add(panel)`.

Comment: *"I have checked these questions.."*  BTW - excellent question what with the extensive research and the code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. ***Don't* set a preferred size on the panel.** See [Should I avoid the use of setPreferred/Maximum/MinimumSize methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556) for the reasons why.
2. **Add *only* the scroll pane to the content pane.**

   1. A content pane using the default layout (`BorderLayout`) will default to putting the component in the `CENTER` constraint if none is supplied, and the `CENTER` area can only accept a single component.
   2. Besides that, the panel has already been added to the scroll pane, it will already appear inside it, and can only appear in a single container.
3. Don't extend frame, just use an instance of one.
4. Don't `setSize`, but `setExtendedState`.
5. GUIs should be constructed and updated on the EDT.
6. A better close operation is `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Question {

    public Question() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("kjdh"));
        }
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        f.pack();
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Question();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, much better as an answer instead of a comment. Although, I would bold 2 as well since both are need to fix the problem and the other are good programming practices.

Comment: @camickr  Good point.  I edited the answer to expand on both points and **emphasize** the 2nd.

Comment: what if I want the program to be full screen? I set the size to make it fullscreen

Comment: *"what if I want the program to be full screen?"*  What ***happens*** if you run the code I posted?  It looks 'full-screen' to me.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, yes it worked but when I add `JmenuBar` to it, the JMenuBar doesn't appear!should I ask it in another question?

Comment: *"in another question?"*  Sounds like a good plan.  That is what I would advise.

Comment: Do You know how to do it for 
panel.setLayout(null);
f.setLayout(null);
?
I want to manually set position for every element.

Comment: @arrowman *"I want to manually set position for every element."* That's not something I'll spend (i.e. waste) time on.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know now that it is wasting of time. Some people informed me. But thanks:-)

Answer (score 5):

You've added an unecessary duplicate panel on the context pane. Instead of:

```
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

use only

```
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

It makes sense as a scrool pane is a container for a panel, so it's enough to add a container on the context pane.

Comment: please without scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));, because is laid to JFrame.CENTER, then is pretty ignored

Comment: Agree with @mKorbel.  See [Should I avoid the use of setPreferred/Maximum/MinimumSize methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556) (basically 'yes') and my example. No 'size guessing' needed.